# avoid &#8220; in PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript, json, encoding, character-encoding

I have a problem with the encodification (i guess). My script gets by ajax a php that generates a JSON file. The think that the JSON is (seen in firebug)

```
["&#8220;This is a word&#8221; This not"]
```

And I wanna to remove `&#8220`. Is there any way to remove this (in php or js, does not matter)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the response text is : "'This is a word'; This not" ?

Comment: Are you saying that the JSON string returned contains the characters represented by `&#8220` and `&#8221` (fancy quotation marks, I believe), or the actual individual characters `&, #, 8, 2, 2, 0`?

Answer (score 0):

For javascript, you can use:

```
var src = "&#8220;This is a word&#8221; This not";
src = src.replace(/&#8220;/gi, "");
```

For php, you can use:

```
$src = "&#8220;This is a word&#8221; This not";
$src = str_replace("&#8220;", "", $src);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["&#8220;This is a word&#8221; This not"]
```

is just one string encoded in JSON. If you want to remove that part of the string (or JSON for the string), you could create the string with the JSON and then use the javascript function replace to remove `&#8220;`.

Try this:

```
var response = ["&#8220;This is a word&#8221; This not"];
response.replace(/&#8220;/g, "");
```

if you actually want it in JSON (which I doubt) you could then turn it back:

```
var response_json = JSON.stringify(response);
```